# Python error inserting data via variable (sqlite3.OperationalError)

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Just want the user to be able to insert a name for a new category into the categories table. But, there's a syntax error.

The table has two columns: id and category_name. The id is auto-increment, I want to just be able to insert the category_name and let the id be auto-generated. If I remove the brackets from `(category_name)` the error message changes from `near ")"` to `near "category_name"`. I've only seen one occurence of someone inserting only one value into a table, maybe the syntax is different in this case.
I hope it's something obvious :)

```py
import sqlite3
database = sqlite3.connect('db/quiz_database.db')
cursor = database.cursor()

category_userinput = input("please input data")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO categories (category_name) VALUES (?,)",
               (category_userinput))
database.commit()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/quiz database project(17-06)/The Quiz/testfile.py", line 7, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO categories (category_name) VALUES (?,)", (category_userinput))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

Comment: @eyllanesc doesn't work, same error

Comment: try this `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO categories (category_name,) VALUES (?,)", (category_userinput,))`

Comment: @Kushan_Gunasekerano sorry guys, same error still :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing comma in your SQL which is invalid SQL syntax. In addition the second parameter to `execute` needs to be a collection type object, currently you are just passing in a string. Simply change:

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO categories (category_name) VALUES (?,)", (category_userinput))
```

to:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO categories (category_name) VALUES (?)", [category_userinput])
```

Comment: No, this isn't the solution, maybe I should've explained this too. Doing what you said gives an error of: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. There is a comma after the `?` because I want it to be a tuple, idk why to be honest but it works that way. Without the comma it interprets the variable (e.g. "test") as a tuple of (t,e,s,t) which doesn't work. (I think)

Comment: Good, so we've got past the first error. Now let's work on this one. What is contained inside `category_userinput`? Are you just trying to add one category at a time?

Comment: whatever the user inputs. Let's say "test". Yeah, just one at a time.

Comment: You don't want it to be a tuple, tuples are a python thing, not sql. You keep saying "think", have you debugged your own code to check? If you just print out the value of category_userinput what do you get, a tuple or a string?

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm using the wrong word (not 'tuple'). category_userinput is a string.

Comment: I think that you can't explain what you mean is going to make it extremely difficult for me to help. A trailing comma in the VALUES list is invalid SQL so that will never work. Now it tells you that you are trying to bind an incorrect number of parameters. What is your current execute line after my suggested changes?

Comment: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO categories (category_name) VALUES (?)", category_userinput)

Comment: That looks fine to me assuming `category_userinput` is a simple string. Have you tried doing `str(category_userinput)` to make 100% sure?

Comment: Also to confirm your id column is setup already as an auto increment column? Have you tried explicitly inserting with an id for now to rule that out as an issue?

Comment: okay so, str(category_userinput) doesn't work. And yes, I have tried setting an id manually (e.g. 6) and that works, no error. that's why I think it's something to do with having only one variable being added.

Comment: Right so that's your issue, the id column. What is your column definition for id. Adding a single value is fine as long as your other column is setup correctly to auto insert a value.

Comment: now it is like this: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO categories (id, category_name) VALUES (?,?)", (6, category_userinput))

Comment: what do you mean column definition?

Comment: The definition of your id column. When you set the table up you'd have to define your columns first.

Comment: actually I set up the database using SQLite Studio software. That's how my teacher told us to do it. I just called it category_name and made it a CHAR with length 15. If that makes sense to you

Comment: And what about the ID column? I'm afraid I haven't used SQLite Studio. It sounds like your ID column is not setup as you think though.

Comment: okay all it says about the id column is: "id", INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY, AUOTOINCREMENT, UNIQUE

Comment: Ok the last thing to try is this. Note the `[]` around the user input value:
`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO categories (category_name) VALUES (?)", [category_userinput])`

Comment: YES! it works haha. Thanks so much for being patient. May I ask how that worked?

Comment: Excellent! A nice little bit of debugging on a Monday morning. It works because originally you had 2 issues. One was that you had the trailing comma in the SQL and the second was that you weren't passing a collection type object to the execute method. We fixed one at the beginning but didn't come back to fix the second but we got there in the end!